# FIDE tourney location

Tags: fide

I have been trying to figure out when a tournament for FIDE will be near but I can't find any in the U.S. Does FIDE not come to the U.S?

Answer (score 3):

Of course FIDE have tournaments in the US.

You can find them on the FIDE website here - https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=USA

Answer (score 3):

Most open tournaments in the US are fide rated.  Besides the fide site you can check the USCF site: http://www.uschess.org/tlas/upcoming.php

Comment: Some may be rated.  Some are not.  The larger the tournament the better the chance it is.  Small local  tournaments just cannot afford the extra costs involved.